# Easy_install cache downloaded files

Tags: python, easy-install, egg, python-wheel

Is there a way to configure easy_install to avoid having to download the files again when an installation fails?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update 13 years later**: `easy_install` was removed from Python in January 2021. The python package manager is `pip`, it caches downloaded packages.

pip (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/) is a drop-in replacement for the easy_install tool and can do that.

Just run `easy_install pip` and set an environment variable `PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE` to the path you want pip to store the files.
Note that the cache won't work with dependencies that checkout from a source code repository (like svn/git/hg/bzr).

Then use `pip install` instead of `easy_install`

Comment: One thing to note is `pip cant install binaries(_.egg files_)`. This is crucial on windows platforms.

Answer (score 13):

Here is my solution using pip, managing even installation of binary packages and usable on both, Linux and Windows. And as requested, it will limit download from PyPi to the minimum, and as extra bonus, on Linux, it allows to speed up repeated installation of packages usually requiring compilation to a fraction of a second.

Setup takes few steps, but I thing, it is worth to do.

## Create pip config file

Create pip configuration file (on linux: ~/.pip/pip.conf, on Windows %HOME%\pip\pip.ini)

My one has this content:

```
[global]
download-cache = /home/javl/.pip/cache
find-links = /home/javl/.pip/packages

[install]
use-wheel = yes

[wheel]
wheel-dir = /home/javl/.pip/packages
```

## Populating `cache` dir - goes automatically

The `cache` dir will get cached version of data downloaded from pypi each time, pip attempts to get some package from pypi. It is easy to get it there (no special care needed), but note, that from pip point of view, these are just cashed data downloaded from PyPi, not packages, so in case you use an option `--no-index`, it will not work.

## `pip download` to populate `packages` dir

The `packages` dir is place to put real package files to. E.g. for my favorite package `plac`, I would do:

```
$ pip download --dest ~/.pip/packages plac
```

and the plac package file would appear in that dir. You may even use `-r requirements.txt` file to do this for multiple packages at once.

These packages are used even with `$ pip install --no-index <something>`.

## Prevent repeated compilation of the same package on Linux

E.g. `lxml` package requires compliation, and download and compile may take from 45 seconds to minutes. Using wheel format, you may save here a lot.

Install `wheel` tool, if you do not have it yet:

```
$ pip install wheel
```

Create the wheel for `lxml` (assuming, you have managed to install `lxml` in past - it requires some libs in the system to be installed):

```
$ pip wheel lxml
```

This goes over download, compile, but finally results in lxml `whl` file being in `packages` dir.

Since then

```
$ pip install lxml
```

or even faster

```
$ pip install --no-index lxml
```

will take fraction of a second, as it uses wheel formatted package.

## Prepare wheel package from Window setup exe package

(note: this can be prepared even on Linux machine, there is no compilation, only some repacking from exe file into `whl`.)

1. download the exe form of the package from pypi, e.g:

   $ wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/l/lxml/lxml-3.2.3.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=14ab978b7f0a3382719b65a1ca938d33
   $ dir
   lxml-3.2.3.win32-py2.7.exe
2. convert it to `whl`

   $ wheel convert lxml-3.2.3.win32-py2.7.exe
   $ dir
   lxml-3.2.3.win32-py2.7.exe
   lxml-3.2.3-cp27-none-win32.whl
3. Test it:

   $ pip install lxml

or

```
$ pip install --no-index lxml
```

shall be very quick.

Note, that `wheel convert` can do exactly the same conversion for egg formatted packages.

## Let `easy_install` and `setup.py install` reuse your `packages` dir

`easy_install` and `$ python setup.py install` do not seem to offer download cache, but allow to use packages we have in our `packages` dir.

To do so, edit config file for these two tools:

On Linux: `$HOME/.pydistutils.cfg`

On Windows: `%HOME%\pydistutils.cfg`

In my case I have here in `/home/javl/.pydistutils.cfg`:

```
[easy_install]
find_links = /home/javl/.pip/packages
```

This config may help even some cases of `pip install` calls, when pip attempts to install a package, declaring dependency on other ones. As it delegates this task to `setup.py` call, without the `.pydistutils.cfg` config it would download the file from PyPi.

Unfortunately, wheel format is not supported in this case (as far as I am aware of).