# apt-get installing older version of packages (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv, package

I'm trying to install `pip` and `virtualenv` on a server (running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS) on which I have access, but I can only do it with `sudo apt-get install` (school politics). The problem is that althought I have run the `sudo apt-get update` command to update the packages list, I think it keeps installing old ones. After doing `sudo apt-get install python-pip python-virtualenv`, I do `pip --version`  on which I get the `1.0`, and `virtualenv --version` on which I get `1.7.1.2`. These two version are quite old (`pip` is already in `1.5.5` and `virtualenv` in `1.11.5`). I read that the problem is that the packages list is not up-to-date, but the command `sudo apt-get update` should solve this, but I guess no. How can I solve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is not a programming question and probably belongs on http://www.superuser.com

Comment: @armadadrive: yes and no, he is asking about programming tools, so might keep this here as well. Anyway, answered, whether it gets migrated or not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-get update` updates packages from Ubuntu package catalog, which has nothing to do with mainstream versions.

`LTS` in Ubuntu stands for Long Term Support. Which means that after a certain period in time they will only release security-related bugfixes to the packages. In general, major version of packages will not change inside of a major Ubuntu release, to make sure backwards-compatibility is kept.

So if then only thing you can do is `apt-get update`, you have 2 options:

- find a PPA that provides fresher versions of packages that you need, add it and repeat the update/install exercise
- find those packages elsewhere, download them in `.deb` format and install.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to use the latest stable versions of Python packages, then do not use `apt-get` for installing Python packages and use pip instead. If you would use `apt-get` and later install the same packages by means of `pip` or (better not) `easy_install` or `setup.py`, you are likely to run into version conflicts wondering, why your python based commands are of unexpected versions, or even worse, why they do not work at all.

I try to follow this pattern:

### 1. system wide pip installation first

Using instructions from here: http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html find `get-pip.py` script, download it and run as python script.

```
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
$ sudo python get-pip.py
$ rm get-pip.py
```

### 2. use pip to install `virtualenv` system wide

this shall be as easy as:

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
```

### 3. (optional) install virtualenvwrapper - system wide or to user profile

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

and follow instructions for configuring it.

### 4. Since now, install inside your virtualenv environments

This shall prevent conflicts between various versions of packages.

You are free to update particular virtualenvs as you need one by one independently.

### 5. (optional) Configure installation cache directories for installation speed

There are method how to speed up repeated installation of packages, what comes handy if you get used using virtualenv often. For details see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18520729/346478

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for. I know very well pip, but as I said, I have only access to 'sudo apt-get' because it is an external server that doesn't belong to me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @tomasyany assuming you have access to Python, you may install the stuff to the user profile.

Comment: I have access to Python, but not to sudo python. Are you saying there's a way to install Python packages only in my user without having sudo? I am using virtual environments to be able to install packages in my on behalf.

Comment: @tomasyany Yes, you can install into your user profile by `$ pip install --user <packagename>` or `$ pip install --user -r requirements.txt`, no need to use `sudo` for that. But if you have reasonably new version of `virtualenv` you have most important stuff available.