# Deploy Python package on Windows, that compiles dependencies, without installing Visual Studio?

Tags: python, windows, pip, pypi, python-wheel

What's the best way to deploy a Python package to a Windows Server if some of the dependencies need to be compiled? Installing Visual Studio is out of the question and I'm reluctant to pass a 250MB file around everytime things need updating. `pip install -r requirements.txt` is the goal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a compile-once, deploy-many-times strategy might help, with the use of Python's newest package distribution format, [wheels](http://pythonwheels.com/). They are an already-compiled, binary format. So the requirements are just a development / build platform that's similar / running the same python as the deployment platform (the latter won't require a build chain anymore).

Install the latest `pip`, `setuptools` and `wheel` packages. You can then use the [`pip wheel`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel.html) command as you would `pip install`, except it will instead produce a folder called (by default) `wheelhouse` full of the necessary, already-compiled wheels for another python/pip to install what you required.

You can then pass those wheel filepaths directly to a `pip install` command (e.g on your deployment machine), or use the normal package name(s) with `--no-index --find-links=` flags to point to the folder location where those wheels are. This location can also be a simple http folder - [for example](https://wheels.caremad.io/).

Comment: Nice, I hadn't heard about `wheels` and seems to be the ticket.

Answer (score 3):

## easy_install - allows installing from exe

`easy_install` does install from exe installers, if they are available. `pip` does not install from `exe`, so in case of C/C++ packages, `easy_install` is often the way to install.

## making `pip` to install binaries

`pip` is supporting installation from `wheel` format.

In case you have a wheel on pypi or another index server you use, allow `pip` to use wheels (--use-wheels). Latest version of `pip` is using wheel format by default, older ones required setting `--use-wheel` switch.

## building wheels

You can either build (compile) wheels, or you can convert eggs or exe installers to wheels.

For this, use `wheel` command.

## Serving packages in wheel format

Some packages (e.g. `lxml`) do not provide wheels on pypi server. If you want to use them, you have to manage your own index. Easiest one is to use dedicated directory and `pip` configured with `--find-links` pointing there.

See [SO answer to caching packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18520729/346478) for more tips and details.

Very good alternative is `devpi` index server, which is easy to set up, has very good workflow and will integrate with your pip very well.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was missing.

Comment: In simple situations you can use the `--find-links` flag instead of a dedicated pypi server :)

Comment: @Ivo Yes, I added reference to related SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18520729/346478