# pip install MySQL-python returns unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have been trying to `pip install MySQL-python` on Windows 7 but it returns `unable to find vcvarsall.bat`. I am using Python 3.4. How can I make this work in a simple way without going through the thorny path of installing Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `pip` is used to install from source code, it requires compilation. There are two options to resolve that:

## Install using `easy_install`

`easy_install` is quickly able to install using compiled exe file.

## Install using `pip` using wheel package format

This is my favorite solution.

You have to get the wheel package format first. Many Python packages have them already and latest version of `pip` will by default install from it, older versions must be used with `--use-wheel` switch.

If wheel does not exist, you shall create one. Install `wheel` package first and use it to convert existing exe or egg file for given platform to wheel.

In case, there is no already compiled version for the package of your interest, there is no other solution than to compile it somewhere. Anyway, once you get it, you can turn into wheel format and install from it.

For further information about [general `pip`, `easy_install` and wheel usage and setup see my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18520729/346478)

Comment: @Clocker I am happy it works for you. Anyway, whenever possible, prefer using pip as easy_install sometime does not allow safe uninstal as pip does. Ideal solution would be, if authors publish the exe converted to wheel format, but you can do so yourself (what is of course a bit more work, but with private pypi servers like `devpi-server` it is not so difficult). Enjoy Python.

Comment: I ended up following the answer from the link you provided and converting the exe to whl -> worked well good findings sr

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) is a great page with windows binaries to install a lot of common python packages.

Here is a link to the [mysql-python downloads](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python)

Comment: Do you know what I should do specifically to solve this? What binary file should I download?

Comment: If you are using python2.7 on a 64-bit windows machine then you would download and run MySQL‑python‑1.2.5.win‑amd64‑py2.7.exe. For a 32-bit machine running python2.6 you would download and run MySQL‑python‑1.2.5.win32‑py2.6.exe